# PowerShell Comparison Trouble, can't make compound comparisons

Tags: powershell, if-statement, comparison-operators

I am having problems making a compound comparison.  I have not been successful at using -ne or -or.  Below is how I think it should work:

```
If (($Var -ne 'Y') -or ($Var -ne 'N') {
     #Logic for error message and loop back to user promt
Else { #Go to another function }
```

Now when I try this, no matter what I put in, I go to my error message and since that loops back around to the user prompt it just makes an infinite loop.  Even if I put in Y or N, I go to the error message.

Now I've broken that code down to the below code, and that works, but I'd much rather do a compound comparison where If the variable is neither "y" or "n", go to error (this is because inputs Y  and N both progress the script to the same part of my code).

```
If ($Var -eq 'Y') {
     #Do action 1
}
ElseIf ($Var -eq 'N') {
     #Do action 1
}
Else {
     #Give error message and loop back to prompt
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If (($Var -ne 'Y') -or ($Var -ne 'N')) {
     #Logic for error message and loop back to user promt
Else { #Go to another function }
```

This would never work since one of the two will always be true and you are using -or.  There is literally a million ways to tackle this problem, but given what you've shown and inferring you gave a multi-step process, this is what I would do:

```
$step1complete = $false
Write-Host "Some question"
do {
  $var = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Y or N"
  if ($var -in @('Y','N')) {
    $step1complete = $true
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "Invalid option!"
  }
} until ($step1complete)
```

Comment: +1, but a quibble: https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2014/oct/24/mind-your-language-literally

Comment: @mklement0 - what's sad is I have oft criticized others for doing that and I didn't even realize that I had!!  I'd edit the post, but then it would make your comment seem out of place, so I'll just have to suffer for my poor judgement.  :)

Comment: :) Unless you prefer to keep the comments for entertainment value, feel free to edit your answer and then flag my comments as "no longer needed".

Comment: I suppose I don't understand how that can always be true, as if the user doesn't enter anything, enters a number, or a different letter, like 'b', then I want the script to go to an error message, but if the user enters Y or N, then I want the script to proceed to the same next line of code....the Y or N only matters later on concerning the execution of other parts of the script.  Sorry for not being so clear about that in my question.

Comment: @Ken  in your question you used the -or operator.  This means if either side is true than the whole operation is try.  Even if you chose Y, the second condition would be true as it does not equal N.  Using the code above it will loop until either Y or N is selected, which is what I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
    If (($Var -ne 'Y') -or ($Var -ne 'N')) {
```

This will always be true.   I think you want to do an "-and" here.

If you try this:

```
$Var = "1"
If (($Var -ne 'Y') -and ($Var -ne 'N')) {
     #Logic for error message and loop back to user promt
      "ne Y or ne N"
     }
Else { #Go to another function 
 "else"
}
```

It should print else"

Comment: I don't think I want an -and, basically if the user inputs anything other than Y or N (say nothing, or a number, or the letter B) then I want it to go to an error message, but if it is Y or N, then the script can proceed as normal.  I'm using the Y and N for setting things up later in the script, so immediately there is no difference, the program executes the same next line of code regardless if Y or N were chosen.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.